# URL Shortener PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm looking to create a URL Shortener, although I'm encountering an issue which I cannot think through. 
I need the user to be able to find his id with a get request using a slash(`/`) instead of a `?=` for example,

Instead of using `oli.pw?id=100` I would need it to be `oli.pw/100`.

I looked into URL rewriting but I honestly have no idea how to accomplish this with all get requests.

If this is not detailed enough leave a comment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /(index\.php)?\?id=([0-9]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%3?%4 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Fantastic, thankyou. Now i have to figure out why it gives me 404's when i try access the url :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short example for some basic url-rewriting,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `.htaccess` file an configure your rewrite rules in there.

You will need something like:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ ?id=$1
```

You should read more about `mod_rewrite` [here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)